# How to use setError in FieldArray?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a initialValues as a list of array

```
   iniitialValues ={
   ranges : [{ fromDate : '', endDate : ''},
   { fromDate : '', endDate : ''},
   { fromDate : '', endDate : ''}]
   }
```

I need to check the case if any of the dates comes between any other dates interval.

Implemented Formik logic, How to use setError in FeildArray
Because the setErrors notation is as follow

```
`    setErrors({name : "ERR"})
`
```

But in my case I need to access the array index to set error.
Getting error while in this line

```
`    setErrors({ranges[someIndex].endDate : "ERR"})
`
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **setFieldError** instead

```
setFieldError(`ranges[someIndex].endDate`, 'This is an error message');
```

Try this one. I hope this will help you